# Ireports query not working

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to add a query in ireports. But it gives me

```
    {
    'collectionName':'weekly_jasper_reports',
    'findQuery':
        {
            '$markets':'"+{'Markets':null}+"'
        }
    }                                                                        
^ 
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:  {'collectionName':'weekly_jasper_reports','findQuery':{'$markets':'"+{'Markets':null}+"'}}                                                                        
^      
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:455)      at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:424)      
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:378)      at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:414)      
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:378)      at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:328)      
at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:287)      at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:272)      
at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryWrapper.processQuery(MongoDbQueryWrapper.java:104)      
at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryWrapper.<init>(MongoDbQueryWrapper.java:93)      
at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryExecuter.createDatasource(MongoDbQueryExecuter.java:117)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1112)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:689)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1281)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:87)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

any suggestions where i am wrong??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clearly something is wrong with the syntax of this bit of JSON. I would imagine that the double quotation marks are obsolete.

Comment: no!! it is still not working. if i give the value directly in query . then it works. in case of promt. it isn't wrking

Comment: Please post some additional information, i.e. how the query looks like in the report design and what is the value that you input in the prompt window.

Comment: Thanks man i found the issue. the query was not correct.
for me 
{'collectionName':'weekly_jasper_reports','findQuery':{'market':'$P!{Market}'}}
worked !!!